# Output one json record react native

Tags: javascript, json, react-native, api

I have an api request that contains 1 json record, how can I display it on the screen?

```
 const [user, setUser] = useState();
   const getUserData = async () => {
    // {headers: {Authorization: "Basic " + base64.encode(username + ":" + password),}}
    try {
      const response = await fetch('http://*******/warrant/' + route.params.id, {headers: {Authorization: "Basic " + base64.encode(username + ":" + password),}});
      json = await response.json();
      
      setUser(json.warrant);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };



useState(() => {
    getUserData();
  }, []);

 return (
    <View >
      <View >
        <Text style={styles.input2}>name:</Text>
      <Text style={styles.input} value={user.name}>{user.name}</Text>
      </View>
```

Error: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'user.name')

json example:

```
{"warrant": {"dateend": "1", "datestart": "1", "description": "1", "fio": "1", "id": 2, "image": "", "name": " 3", "number": "4", "numberitem": "4", "state": 2}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write `const [user, setUser] = useState();`, you're calling useState with an empty argument.  That means `user` is undefined by default, and unsafe to access.  There are two easy solutions to this:

1. safely access the name property: `user?.name` instead of `user.name`
2. assign a default object to user: `const [user, setUser] = useState({});`

For more see:

- [the docs for useState](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html)
- [MDN docs on the optional chaining operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)